# Flash Video Chat SDK/Component

Tags: flash, sdk, components, videochat

I am looking to integrate video chat functionality in our existing web-app. Now I have the following three solutions:

1. Develop my own in flash
2. Tokbox.com
3. Oovoo.com
4. Any other services?

Does anyone have any experience (good/bad) using the above services or would like to suggest any other service? I only want one-to-one chat (preferably without any branding).

Should I develop my own (reinvent the wheel) or is there some good available component?

Any suggestions? Thoughts?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/afcs/) seems to have what you need, but you would be relying on their service which is in beta. Pricing plan and things like that might change in time, but no branding yet and maybe it's worth a try.

Comment: Depending on what you need, I think <a href="http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/afcs/">AFCS is a good call</a>. We'll be announcing pricing very, very soon.

=Ryan ryan@adobe.com